# Pandas dataframe column needs to pass as an input to another function

Tags: python, pandas

I am newbie in python so please help me out .

I have a function in my client api -:

```
def captureserial() -> None :
ser_no          = xxxx
inc_exp         = "Yes"
inc_exp_flag    = inc_exp.lower()[0] == "y"
args = {
    "serial_number":    ser_no,
    "include_expired":  inc_exp_flag,
}

ret, stat = apic_send_rq("certs", args)
print(ser_no)

qualify = "All" if inc_exp_flag else "Non-expired"
output("%s case with serial number '%s'" % (qualify, ser_no), stat, ret)
```

This is my dataframe

```
sg.theme('Light Blue 2')

layout = [[sg.Text('Enter  files to upload')],
[sg.Text('File 1', size=(8, 1)), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
      
[sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]
window = sg.Window('File', layout)

event, values = window.read()
window.close()
print(f'You clicked {event}')
print(f'You chose filenames {values[0]}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_excel(values[0],usecols = [0])
    print(df)
    df.columns=['PluginOutput']
    df['Serial Number'] =df['PluginOutput'].apply(lambda x: find_serialnumber(x))
    df['Serial Number'] = df['Serial Number'].str.replace(' ','')
    print(df)
```

I want to pass one of the column (Serial Number) of my data frame into the function "captureserial()" so it a take the serial Number and process the data accordingly and give me a output, which I have to write in an excel sheet.

How can I pass a single data frame column to another function and capture the output returned by that function in excel sheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use function `apply` of a Series (because df['PluginOutput'] is a Series object, check it out) you pass each value to the function used inside the `apply`. So the function should take a `PluginOutput` and return desired value (not Series and not DataFrame - the value itself). To save just use `to_excel` fun e.g.  `df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')`